# Application of Dependency Inversion Principle

Tags: architecture, solid, dependency-inversion

Not a new programmer but new to architecture design. I'm about halfway through "Clean Architecture" by Robert C. Martin and I've realized that few components in my program need to have their dependencies inverted. The program is using C#/ASP.NET MVC but that shouldn't be relevent.

One example is the **Investigation** component. The gist of this workflow is that the **Web** creates and runs an `Investigation`. The `Investigation` creates a list of `ICheck` based on its configuration and runs them. A `CheckImplementation` is more often than not just a passthrough to an `ApiIntegration`, although some `CheckImplementation` need to use the database. There are currently 10 `CheckImplementation` and the system should be designed for that number to be grow easily.

The current architecture is as follows:

[image]

**Investigation** violates all sorts of principles, Stable Dependency Principle, Stable and Not Abstract (Zone of Pain), etc.

I redesigned my architecture by:

- Check implementation and API integration have been consolidated into **CheckImplementations**, which replaces the old **ApiIntegrations**. This eliminates the redundant `CheckImplementation`->`ApiIntegration` structure from before.
- Inverted the **Investigation**->**ApiIntegrations**/**CheckImplementations** dependency, which creates a Stable/Abstract dependency in favor of a Concrete dependency.
- Used the Factory pattern to achieve the Dependency Inversion.

[image: Architecture After]

Is this a good application of Dependency Inversion Principal? I'm familiar with using dependency inversion at the class-level via Dependency Injection, but using it at the component-level is an entirely new concept to me.

Also, I didn't include it in the diagram but I have a **Models** component which only contains data structures. Instead of creating an entirely new component for the `ICheck` interface, would it be wise to just place it in **Models**?

Comment: Is the main issue here that Investigation is creating the CheckImplementation instances?   To introduce a dependency injection, you can simply have something else (e.g. InvestigationUtility) create the ICheck instances and pass them to Investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't achieved anything with your redesign, the `Investigation` module is still transitively dependent on `CheckImplementations` module.

To properly achieve the decoupling of your `Investigation` and `CheckImplementation` modules, it would be necessary to create `ICheckFactory` interface, so that dependency between `Investigation` and CheckFactory is inverted, eg. `CheckFactory` depends on `Investigation` through the ICheck interface.

After that I would recommend to simplify the design by moving `ICheck` and `ICheckFactory` into `Investigation` module and `Check` and `CheckFactory` into `CheckImplementations` module. Combined with the above, the `CheckImplementations` module would depend on `Investigation` module, resulting in inverted dependency compared to what you have now.

Comment: Great solution, I was worried that `Investigation` was still transitively dependent on `CheckImplementations`. After redesigning to your suggestions would it just be a matter of using dependency injection to give `Investigation` the correct implementation of `ICheckFactory`?

Comment: @zwaller Yes, exactly.